# libgdx facebook sdk NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: libgdx, facebook-android-sdk

I keep getting `NoClassDefFoundError` while trying to add Facebook login functionality in my libgdx project.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.LoggingBehavior[]
        at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.<clinit>(FacebookSdk.java:63)
        at com.example.app.android.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I do have in build.gradle

```
compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0"
```

From inside AndroidLauncher I can refer classes from this jar

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

or even the one that is suppose to be missing, mainly `LoggingBehavior` and still for no good reason on runtime the class is not there.

Comment: Is it gradle that gives this message? Or some IDE?

Comment: gradle build works just fine. It's the AVD/emulator Nexus 5 API 19 I use IntelliJ. It happens on run time. Btw. when I do reference that class from code it works just fine, meaning I can for example do `final LoggingBehavior appEvents = LoggingBehavior.APP_EVENTS;`